# how to read the data from a dataset ?? I am getting the data as System.Data.DataRowCollection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to get the data from this data object team and I am passing it to a list. when I am running the program instead of Data I am getting System.Data.DataRowCollection. please let me know whats the wrong thing that i am doing here ?

```
public ActionResult notifications()
{
    List<notifications> Teamwon = Getsports();
    return View(Teamwon);
}
public List<notifications> Getsports()
{
    string lname;
    string lvenue;
    string ldate;
    string lteam1;
    string lteam2;
    string leaname = "0";
    string leavenue = "0";
    string leadate = "0";
    string wteam = "0";

    SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Remember;server=DESKTOP-59SGH72\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=sport;Trusted_Connection=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter usersport = new SqlDataAdapter("select sports_details_id from users_sports_following where user_id ='" + Session["userid"] + "'", sqlConnection1);
    DataSet sportds = new DataSet();
    usersport.Fill(sportds);
    int count = sportds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    List<string[]> leaguelist = new List<string[]>();
     List<string[]> teamlist = new List<string[]>();
    while (count != 0)
    {
        Int16 id = Convert.ToInt16(sportds.Tables[0].Rows[count-1]["sports_details_id"].ToString());

       using (SqlDataAdapter leagueDetails = new SqlDataAdapter("select league_name, league_details_venue,league_details_date,sports_details_id1,sports_details_id2 from leagues, league_details where sports_details_id1 in ('" + id + "') or sports_details_id2 in ('" + id + "')", sqlConnection1))
        {
            DataSet leagues = new DataSet(); 
            leagueDetails.Fill(leagues).ToString();

            lname = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["league_name"].ToString();
            lvenue = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["league_details_venue"].ToString();
            ldate = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["league_details_date"].ToString();
            lteam1 = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sports_details_id1"].ToString();
            lteam2 = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sports_details_id2"].ToString();

            string[] fields = new string[5];
            fields[0] = lname;
            fields[1] = lvenue;
            fields[2] = ldate;
            fields[3] = lteam1;
            fields[4] = lteam2;
            leaguelist.Add(fields);
        } 
        count = count - 1;
    }           
    List<notifications> notificationlist = new List<notifications>();
    foreach (string[] fields in leaguelist)
    {
         leaname = fields[0];
         leavenue = fields[1];
         leadate = fields[2];
        var id1 = fields[3];
        var id2 = fields[4];

        SqlConnection sqlConnection2 = new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Remember;server=DESKTOP-59SGH72\\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=True;Database=sport");
        SqlDataAdapter ds = new SqlDataAdapter("team", sqlConnection2);
        ////mention the adaptor that it needs to ru stored procedure
        ds.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        ds.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@sports_details_id1", id1);
        ds.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@sports_details_id2", id2);

        //fill the dataset
        DataSet da = new DataSet();
        ds.Fill(da).ToString();
        string team = da.Tables[0].Rows.ToString();
        notificationlist.Add( new notifications
        {
            leaguename = leaname,
            leaguevenue = leavenue,
            date = leadate,
            teamwon = team
        });
    }
    return notificationlist;
}
```

}

I was trying to get the data from this data object team and I am passing it to a list. when I am running the program instead of Data I am getting System.Data.DataRowCollection. please let me know whats the wrong thing that i am doing here ?

```
public ActionResult notifications()
{
    List<notifications> Teamwon = Getsports();
    return View(Teamwon);
}
public List<notifications> Getsports()
{
    string lname;
    string lvenue;
    string ldate;
    string lteam1;
    string lteam2;
    string leaname = "0";
    string leavenue = "0";
    string leadate = "0";
    string wteam = "0";

    SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Remember;server=DESKTOP-59SGH72\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=sport;Trusted_Connection=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter usersport = new SqlDataAdapter("select sports_details_id from users_sports_following where user_id ='" + Session["userid"] + "'", sqlConnection1);
    DataSet sportds = new DataSet();
    usersport.Fill(sportds);
    int count = sportds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    List<string[]> leaguelist = new List<string[]>();
     List<string[]> teamlist = new List<string[]>();
    while (count != 0)
    {
        Int16 id = Convert.ToInt16(sportds.Tables[0].Rows[count-1]["sports_details_id"].ToString());

       using (SqlDataAdapter leagueDetails = new SqlDataAdapter("select league_name, league_details_venue,league_details_date,sports_details_id1,sports_details_id2 from leagues, league_details where sports_details_id1 in ('" + id + "') or sports_details_id2 in ('" + id + "')", sqlConnection1))
        {
            DataSet leagues = new DataSet(); 
            leagueDetails.Fill(leagues).ToString();

            lname = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["league_name"].ToString();
            lvenue = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["league_details_venue"].ToString();
            ldate = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["league_details_date"].ToString();
            lteam1 = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sports_details_id1"].ToString();
            lteam2 = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sports_details_id2"].ToString();

            string[] fields = new string[5];
            fields[0] = lname;
            fields[1] = lvenue;
            fields[2] = ldate;
            fields[3] = lteam1;
            fields[4] = lteam2;
            leaguelist.Add(fields);
        } 
        count = count - 1;
    }           
    List<notifications> notificationlist = new List<notifications>();
    foreach (string[] fields in leaguelist)
    {
         leaname = fields[0];
         leavenue = fields[1];
         leadate = fields[2];
        var id1 = fields[3];
        var id2 = fields[4];

        SqlConnection sqlConnection2 = new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Remember;server=DESKTOP-59SGH72\\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=True;Database=sport");
        SqlDataAdapter ds = new SqlDataAdapter("team", sqlConnection2);
        ////mention the adaptor that it needs to ru stored procedure
        ds.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        ds.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@sports_details_id1", id1);
        ds.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@sports_details_id2", id2);

        //fill the dataset
        DataSet da = new DataSet();
        ds.Fill(da).ToString();
        string team = da.Tables[0].Rows.ToString();
        notificationlist.Add( new notifications
        {
            leaguename = leaname,
            leaguevenue = leavenue,
            date = leadate,
            teamwon = team
        });
    }
    return notificationlist;
}
```

}
}

please help me with how to get the data from team object..!! i am sending the notification list to my view. I am getting all the data except the data from team object

Comment: is your team a string?

Comment: @msoliman yes it is..

Comment: and you want to access its fields?, I'm trying to understand your code

Comment: If you want to access this object "team" and get its attributes and fields, you don't have to convert it to string. you should keep it as it is. is it one team or multiple teams ???

Comment: @msoliman ya it returns a string value which comes from a stored procedure

Comment: @msoliman most of the times its multiple. The values depends on the the for loop,  i mean how many values goes through the for loop

Comment: you are converting rows directly to a string, you should loop through all rows that came from database and combine them into a string but not to use "Rows.ToString()" directly, I think this is your problem. if you want me to put an answer for you I can however I need to make sure what I understand is your actual problem

Comment: @msoliman I tried removing the conversion , i just tried using   string team = da.Tables[0].Rows; it returns an error saying  cannot implicitly convert the type system.data.datarowcollection to string

Comment: @msoliman i guess that's the reason, please let me know how to do it !!

Comment: plz chk the answer, you should know what columnName you want to put though in your code, if my answer helped you plz mark as a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem should be solved using the following snippet code, `columnName` should be changed to your actual name of the column. if you have multiple columns, you can combine them all in the same line.

```
string team = "";

for(var row in da.Tables[0].Rows){
 team += row["columnName"];
}
```

Comment: on row it shows a error implicitly typed local variables must be initialized. what should i initialize it with.. please let me know